# Write a Python program to guess a number between 1 to 9

Tags: python

Write a Python program to guess a number between 1 to 9
**Note : User is prompted to enter a guess. If the user guesses wrong then the prompt appears again until the guess is correct, on successful guess, user will get a "Well guessed!" message, and the program will exit.**

The above statement is given.. i have written code but it hangs after giving input.. after ctr+c it shows last call on if statement.

```
from random import randint as rt
g= rt(1,9)
ug= int(input("Guess a number"))
while True:
    if g==ug:
        print("Well guessed!")
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: "not working" is not an adequate description of the problems you are observing in your program.

Comment: Your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like to know what actually happens inside the while loop versus what is expected to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OP**:

*i have written code but it hangs after giving input.. after ctr+c it shows last call on if statement.*

**Because**:

Imagine you've entered an incorrrect number, the condition fails, the loop continues, it checks the same condition and fails again, keeps going on and on.

**What you need**:

1. Put the `ug = int(input("Guess a number"))` inside the while loop.
2. Put an `else` block with a `Incorrect Guess` prompt message.

**Hence**:

```
from random import randint as rt
g= rt(1,9)

while True:
    ug = int(input("Guess a number: "))
    if g==ug:
        print("Well guessed!")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect!\n")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Guess a number: 4
Incorrect!

Guess a number: 5
Incorrect!

Guess a number: 6
Incorrect!

Guess a number: 7
Incorrect!

Guess a number: 8
Well guessed!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked very well